# deploy Restheart at kubernetes running mongodb sharded db

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, restheart

I have a running mongodb using sharding. I have made all the services i need, and i have mongodb uri to connect to mongos router. Now i want to use restheart container for http requests. I tried this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: restheart
  labels:
    app: restheart
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: restheart
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: restheart
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: restheart-demo
        image: softinstigate/restheart
        #command:
                #- "--envFile /opt/restheart/etc/default.properties"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        env:
        - name: MONGO_URI
          value: "mongodb://(uri here)"
```

then i used:

```
kubectl expose deploy restheart  --port 8080 --type NodePort
```

but get Requests return 401 code. I have to mention here that at my mongo uri i also included username:password, so that restheart not need to authenticate.
how can i change the default settings of restheart at my yaml so that i can use it properly.
There no documentation at all for restheart running at kubernetes
My problem is that i dont know how to configure restheart when building my deploy with yaml file

Comment: HTT 401 is Unauthorized. Did you pass the credentials on your requests? Check https://restheart.org/docs/security/how-clients-authenticate/

Answer (score 1):

If you will check [this URL](https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart/blob/master/core/etc/default.properties).

You can see default value for mongo-uri = mongodb://127.0.0.1
You cant override this with environment variable. Instead, use volume mounts to replace that specific file with a configmap containing this file with changes and things should work.

Comment: thanks for your answer , i will check this out. As i am very new to kubernetes, can you please provide an example with volume mount? i would be gratefull. If not, thanks in advance. But let me comment this:You cant override this with environment variable
my enviroment variable worked. But you are right, for further configuration i must do volume mount

Comment: check this link https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/

Comment: as i read restheart don't use insert command with post, instead it uses find and modify. That's a problem with sharding mongo:   Write request for sharded collection must specify the shardkey. Use the 'shardkey' query parameter"

Comment: If you don't know much K8s then another option is to edit the properties file (https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart/tree/master/core/etc/default.properties) and re-build the docker image with "docker build -t softinstigate/restheart ." Look at the Dockerfile https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart/blob/master/core/Dockerfile